# Searching in Solr

Tags: mysql, magento, solr

I am building an ecommerce project where I am using solr search engine.I want to search based on specific keyword. If I enter "c1234" , it should display all the documents having keyword "c1234". Its working fine. But, if I enter "c12#34" then also it should consider "c1234" only. So the problem is I want to ignore the hash tag here. Solr should not consider my hash tag and it should display the same result for both the cases.

The other problem is I want to trim whitespaces. If I search "HP 940", it should trim the whitespace and should display the similar result as "HP940". So I want to have similar reults to be displayed with or without the whitespace. For example,
 if I enter "Hp 940", solr should consider it as "HP940". So the problem is triming the white spaces

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use olr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Test case:
[image]

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1"
            generateNumberParts="1" catenateNumbers="0" splitOnNumerics="1"
            catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"
            stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

To replace **#** you should use https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CharFilterFactories

Comment: The solution which u mentioned above is good but i tried using it it's not working and I want the same results for both the cases by triming white space.

Comment: @VaidehiJariwala make sure that you're using right filters for right field types.WordDelimiterFilterFactory works in both directions with a white space and without.See the example above.

Comment: I tried using the exact code which you gave for the right field type but still it's not working for me at all. Any solution for this?

Comment: @VaidehiJariwala have you tried to use SOLR UI analyzer tool? It will help you to understand which filters are you using for query and index.

Comment: Do u know that whether WordDelimeterFilterFactory performs "AND" search or "OR" search.Because I entered "HP 140"(Including White Space) then I am getting results for either "HP" or "140" or "both". i just want the results where Hp and 140 are present anywhere in the string.For example, If I have string like "Hp i7core 5GBRAm 140", another string as "HP140" , third string as "HP i7" then it should return only 1st and 2nd string.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @VaidehiJariwala if you have space between words I suggest you to boolean queries  (Field:HP) AND (Field:140) , without a space it would search in both directions in sol. Or Try to use phrase search using quotes "HP 140" it will match using AND conditions. (but taht case you can't use partial match and fuzzy search)

Comment: I tried using boolean query with "AND" search but not able to retrieve the strings which do not contain the space. For example, "HP140", "HP140 abc" are not retrieved. Only Strings like "abc HP jcdjvc 140", "HP   140" , etc are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

For the hashtag and other characters you should take a look at the solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory for this with the catenateWords parameter or alternatively the solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.

For words like HP 940 also consider something like phrase fields on the dismax handler with no slop.